# Type mismatch, Scanning from String to Object

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm Trying to read from the scanner to a class object but I'm getting

```
type mismatch: cannot convert from String to otherClass

private class myClass() {
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x;
    otherClass A;
    otherClass B;
    A = scan.next();
}
```

In this instance the `otherClass` has a host of variables, however I only need to scan a name as a string so I can compare it with an `ArrayList` of other objects in the class.

Not sure quite where I'm going wrong, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `next()` returns a String, you cannot assign it to `A`, which is of type `otherClass` (should be renamed to `OtherClass` for readability).

Comment: share the body of OtherClass

Comment: If `OtherClass`'s constructor accepts a String, you probably want to do `OtherClass A = new OtherClass(scan.next());`

Comment: @MarounMaroun Have you seen the private modifier used for `otherClass` which looks like an `outer Class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's odd that you want to do things this way.

In Object Oriented Language, we use constructor to initialize variables in  instances.

If you insist on using scanner to input the name in your OtherClass, you'd better go this way.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class OtherClass {

    public String name;

    public OtherClass(String name){

        this.name = name;

    }

}

public class MyClass {

    int x;
    OtherClass a;
    OtherClass b;

    public MyClass(){

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


        this.a = new OtherClass(scanner.next());
        this.b = new OtherClass(scanner.next());
        // always close resources after use
        scanner.close();
    }

    //  testing
    public static void main(String args []){

        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        System.out.println("the name in OtherClass a is: "+myClass.a.name);
        System.out.println("the name in OtherClass b is: "+myClass.b.name);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scanner objects always read Strings. You have to take the String object that is returned by scan.next() and then pass it into your otherClass objects as necessary. A and B are both of type otherClass so (unless otherClass is a superclass of String) you cannot assign a String object to a reference of type otherClass.

Also, the Java convention is to capitalize class names, not camelCase them, so you should use OtherClass.

Answer (score 0):

```
       // here scan.next() reads the string but cannot be
      // convert to the type otherClass.
     A = scan.next(); //raise ClassCastException
```

`String` is only convertible to `Object` Class because `Object` is a `parent` Class for all `Class` you creating in `java`.

You cannot even extend `String` Class because it is declared as  `final` So, This `Class String` never be a `parent` for any `otherclass`

So, `String` object reference can only be holded by either `String` or `Object` Class.

You may change your code like this.

```
  class OtherClass {
  public String readString;  //extra String ref Variable to hold String object.
  }

class myClass() {  //remove private modifier too. because a outer class never be a private.
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x;
    OtherClass A;
     A = new OtherClass();
     A.readString = scan.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this 
let assume Otherclass have Arraylist like this.
        ArrayList arraylist=new ArrayList();
        arraylist.add(scanner.nextInt());

to compare between string and object in the arraylist
        String s1=scanner.next();
        String s2=otherclass.arraylist.get(0).toString();
        System.out.println(s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2));

but you have to override toString() method in the class that you have in the array list.